# Linq group by and order by multiple conditions

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following:

```
myFilteredContractors = (From c In myFilteredContractors
    Join cc In myConClasses On c.ContractorId Equals cc.ContractorId
    Where inClassifications.Contains(cc.ClassificationId)
    Group c By Key = cc.ContractorId Into Group, Count = Count()
    Order By Count Descending
    Select (From c1 In myContractors Where c1.ContractorId = Key).FirstOrDefault).ToList
```

This is properly ordering this list of contractors by the number of classifications that they have.

I also want to order them by whether or not they have a field set (`CompanyOverview`), which if is an empty string should be below those contractors who have set their `CompanyOverview`. Also, after the `CompanyOverview` is ordered I want to order by Registration Date.

So it should order by:

1. Number of Classifications
2. Whether Overview has been set (`c.CompanyOverview`)
3. Registration Date (`c.AppliedDate`)

Is it possible to all of this in LINQ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to order by multiple columns using VB.Net lambda expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743661/how-to-order-by-multiple-columns-using-vb-net-lambda-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add one order by clause after another: order by X, order by Y, ...

If you fancy lambda check `OrderBy()` and `ThenBy()` functions.

Comment: I've tried adding a second order by, and I get c is not declared or in the current scope. Any idea why I don't have access to c in the order by context?